# Retrieving Data from AudioKit's FFT Plot

Tags: ios, fft, microphone, audio-processing, audiokit

I'm working on a project that involves recording audio from the microphone of the iPhone, then feeds it through a Fast Fourier Transform (FFT).

I've found [AudioKit.io](http://audiokit.io) has a demo in which it actively monitors microphone input and can display a plot of the FFT.

I have equations and logarithms that I plan to analyze the audio data with, so
all I really need help with is retrieving the FFT data that is sent to this plot in AudioKit. I'm having a hard time finding the functions/methods that drive the data that fills this plot.

Can anyone point out where to find this FFT data in AudioKit?

Answer (score 4):

The FFT code that AudioKit uses is pretty standard.  You could take AudioKit's Plot and reappropriate the code as you wish:

https://github.com/AudioKit/AudioKit/blob/develop/AudioKit/Common/User%20Interface/AKNodeFFTPlot.swift

Comment: So what's in the buffer, should be the data I'm after. Correct?

Comment: Yes, that is what you'll use.

Comment: How might one access buffer data in iOS using swift or objective c? I've never needed to do this before and a quick google search turned up rather dry.